# When JS source map files downloading to the client?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

When JS source map files downloading to the client?

Are they downloading only when i am using chrome DevTools?

the map files are big and i am afraid it will affect the loading time of the site.

Comment: Don't include source maps when you deploy the project?

Comment: the files may help on production also.. therefore i am asking if it will affect the site download speed...

Comment: If you download anything, it affects the download speed. I mean.. it's just pure logic, why would you even need to ask? If you download extra 300kb of source maps, it affects the bandwith for 300kb that need to be transferred.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this using the chrome://net-internals. Looking at the event log while loading a script with the devtools closed results in just 1 URL_REQUEST.

[image: dev-tools-closed]

Doing the same request with chrome devtools open results into multiple URL_REQUESTS as seen in the screenshot.

[image]

I have not tested this in other browsers other than Chrome 61. I would recommend looking at your server access logs to figure out what other browsers are doing.